# What is " DWARF error: could not find abbrev number 67"

Tags: c, cmake

I am trying to build library with cmake tool chain
but facing with "bin/ld: DWARF error: could not find abbrev number 67"

Could someone explain in which consequences this would occur

Comment: DWARF is the debugging format used with ELF (Executable and Linkable Format), see e.g. [here](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/writing-a-linux-debugger-elf-dwarf/). I don't know the reason for the error, could be mismatching versions of tools in the tool chain, could be lots of other things. You can also try to turn off the including of debugging information (usually `-g`). If `ld` continues despite the error (you didn't tell), probably the worst consequence is that the debugging information is not usable.